# Jquery hide call back function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, callback

i have used this function in the coding but the callback function not works.

```
var supplier_code = $("#supplier_code").val();
$('#copy_item-table tr').not('.'+supplier_code).hide("fast", function(){
    var count = $('#copy_item-table tbody tr:visible').length;
    if(count == 0){
       $('.copy-potable-header').hide();
       $('.copy-item-error').show();
    }else{
       $('.copy-item-error').hide();
       $('.copy-potable-header').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add a FIDDLE ?

Comment: i think the issue is because of tr:visible

Comment: you have to add your markup too

Comment: `.not(document.getElementsByClassName(supplier_code)).hide`.Try this once and [check_this_link] (http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: @Shubham that could cause in syntax error.

Comment: Use **fadeOut(0,function** instead of **hide(fast,function**

Answer (score 0):

Use `fadeOut()` instead of `hide()`